# Choosing AC-AC PSU spec

Tags: power-supply

I am wanting to provide +ve and -ve 12V power rails from a 12 AC PSU using the appropriate rectification, regulators, smoothing caps etc.

The max current draw on the +ve rail is 1300mA and 800mA  on the -ve rail.

I have found a 1600mA PSU.  Am I correct in thinking this will provide enough current, because the draw on the + and - rail isn't at the same time?

Or should I be looking at the total of both rails (plus headroom) e.g. 2.5-3A.

Comment: just to get this straight: you want +12 V DC, -12 V DC and 0 V, right? Where do your max 1300 mA and 800 mA flow, exactly?

Comment: both flow to ground

Comment: and your groud is the 0V, right?

Comment: Yes gnd = 0v - when I say "+ and - rail isn't at the same time",   I mean that that the AC voltage as only ever in a +ve stage or -ve stage.  It can't be +ve and -ve at the same time.  Sorry if this caused confusion.  Obviously the op amp rails both need to be powered all the time.

Comment: that makes no sense – you're current draw is related to the output, not the instantaneous input current.

Comment: Ah OK thanks. I think it was wishful thinking by me that it could supply 1600mA to both rails!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably using the wrong term. You've got a 12 V AC **transformer** rather than a PSU which usually means a lot more than just a transformer.

You can clear some of your confusion by doing the power calculations.

- Transformer rating: 12 V × 1.6 A = 19.2 W.
- Output required: (12 V × 1.3 A) + (12 V × 0.8 A) = 25.2 W.

The problem should be clear by now - and we haven't started to look at power lost to rectification and voltage regulation. If you're doing this with linear regulators you might be looking at another 25% to 40% power loss.

You need more iron and copper! Or get a suitable switched-mode power supply which will be smaller, lighter and much more efficient.

Comment: Many thanks for the clear explanation. Amazingly after a lot of searching, I did manage to find a 12VAC PSU that can provide enough power. I had been going down the switch-mode route. As you say far more efficient and easier to find suitable DC PSUs.  But... I've hit major issues with the modulation being picked up on the audio lines. I must have done about 5 revisions of the board, been in touch with Texas Instruments etc. Kinda can't face any more debugging with the switched mode design, so I'll give the linear regulator method a try. Dissipating the heat isn't an issue. Big metal case!

Comment: I'm glad this helped. Don't forget to accept the answer to indicate to the system that your question has been answered satisfactorily. (You can wait a day or two to encourage other answers which may give you further insights.)